# PARI/GP and gcc

Tags: build, ansi-c, pari

I am trying to install PARI/GP and in the configuration step I get:

```
$ ./Configure
[...]
Looking for the compilers ...
...cc is /usr/bin/cc
...gcc is /usr/local/bin/gcc
GNU compiler version 4.8.0 20120705 (experimental) (GCC)
###
### C compiler does not work. PARI/GP requires an ANSI C compiler! Aborting.
###
### Compiler was: /usr/local/bin/gcc  
$ gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 4.8.0 20120705 (experimental)
```

This is strange because the documentation says:

```
"Only ANSI C and C++ compilers are supported.  Choosing the GNU compiler
gcc/g++ enables the inlining of kernel routines (about 20% speedup; if you
use g++, it is a good idea to include the -fpermissive flag).  If you choose
not to use gcc, the C++ version of Pari will be a little faster because of
general inlining, but can be used in library mode only with C++ programs.
We strongly recommand using gcc all the way through."
```

I have also tried with g++ with the same result.

I am trying to compile on a linux x86_64.

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance,

M;

Answer (score 1):

The config/get_cc script in PARI's top level tried to compile a test program
and failed.

Look for the line

```
$CC $CFLAGS $extraflag -o $exe ansi.c 2>/dev/null && $RUNTEST $exe
```

and remove the 2>/dev/null. Configure should now print out explicit error
messages from the compiler. They should provide a hint.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. This question was asked 9 months ago and I don't remember how I solved it, but I will come back to this if I find the same issue again.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Here is the solution for Linux Mint 17.1 64-bit:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc libc6-dev libgmp-dev
```

This command also installs the GMP library (recommended for PARI/GP).

Thanks to K.B. for the hint on how to see the problem.